# Constructor syntax for Thread class

Tags: c#, constructor, delegates

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Program1.ThreadMethod));
```

I want to know why we write in the constructor `new ThreadStart(Program1.ThreadMethod)`.

Please explain.

Comment: Explain what? What do you really need help with? You have to pass a `ThreadStart` instance to the constructor so of course it has to come from somewhere. One way is to create it explicitly with `new ThreadStart(...)`. What don't you understand, _specifically_?

Comment: what is instance variable and why we are passing it to constructor ?

Comment: _"what is instance variable and why we are passing it to constructor?"_ -- no variable value is being passed, just a newly created instance. As for why, well...because it's _required_. Without it, the `Thread` object would have no idea what method to use as the top-level entry point for the thread that the `Thread` object represents.

Comment: one more thing can you tell me which class instance is it becuase it not formate like class obj  its only  the new class so can you explain where is its  ThreadStart obj = new ThreadStart ???/

Comment: _"where is its ThreadStart obj = new ThreadStart"_ -- there's no need for that. You could declare a variable `obj`, and assign it in that way, and then pass `obj` to the `Thread()` constructor. But there's no requirement that the value of an expression be stored in a variable before being passed. You can instead, as in the example here, simply use the expression directly as the constructor argument. The value is then assigned to the constructor parameter directly when the method is called.

Comment: sir one more thing can you explain in following statement

Comment: Shape s = new Circle(); why we create refrecent to circle, what are its benifits

Answer (score 0):

To start a thread using an instance method for the thread procedure, use the instance variable and method name when you create the ThreadStart delegate. Beginning in version 2.0 of the .NET Framework, the explicit delegate is not required.